# class javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to class sm_cw.model.Intersect

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to load an fxml for my game, it goes through other classes when the start button is clicked ,but when it reaches this class (Actor.java), this error pops up, I understand what the error means, but I can't figure out how to solve it in this context.

Class for Actor (contains methods that describes the objects in the game)

```
public abstract class Actor extends ImageView{

    private double xpos;
    private double ypos;


    public Actor(String imageLink, double xpos, double ypos) {
        setImage(new Image(imageLink));
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
    }

    public void resetActor() {
        setX(xpos);
        setY(ypos);
    }

    /**
     * to set the movement speed of obstacles & frog
     * @param dx
     * @param dy
     */
    public void move(double dx, double dy) {
        setX(getX() + dx);
        setY(getY() + dy);
    }

    public Intersect getIntersect(){
        return (Intersect) getParent();
    }

    public <A extends Actor> java.util.List<A> getIntersectingObjects(java.lang.Class<A> cls){
        ArrayList<A> someArray = new ArrayList<A>();
        for (A actor: getIntersect().getObjects(cls)) {
            if (actor != this && actor.intersects(this.getBoundsInLocal())) {
                someArray.add(actor);
            }
        }
        return someArray;
    }
```

Intersect.java (methods for when the animal (the main game object) intersects with an obstacle)

```
public class Intersect extends Pane {

    public Intersect() {

        sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable, Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) {
                if (newValue != null) {
                    newValue.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                            if (getOnKeyReleased() != null)
                                getOnKeyReleased().handle(event);
                            List<Actor> myActors = getObjects(Actor.class);
                            for (Actor anActor : myActors) {
                                if (anActor.getOnKeyReleased() != null) {
                                    anActor.getOnKeyReleased().handle(event);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    newValue.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                            if (getOnKeyPressed() != null)
                                getOnKeyPressed().handle(event);
                            List<Actor> myActors = getObjects(Actor.class);
                            for (Actor anActor : myActors) {
                                if (anActor.getOnKeyPressed() != null) {
                                    anActor.getOnKeyPressed().handle(event);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }

            }

        });

    }
    public <A extends Actor> List<A> getObjects(Class<A> cls) {
        ArrayList<A> someArray = new ArrayList<A>();
        for (Node n: getChildren()) {
            if (cls.isInstance(n)) {
                someArray.add((A)n);
            }
        }
        return someArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Actor` imageview object isn't inside an `Intersect` pane.

Comment: [mcve] please ..